# How to use fadeTo, etc. animation tags along with a css change statement in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many statements like this:

```js
$('#prof').css('background-image','url("images/select2.png")');
```

I want the change to happen with an animation effect like FadeIn etc. I am using this but it is not working:

```js
$('#prof').css('background-image','url("images/select2.png")').fadeIn( "slow");
```

neither is this working:

```js
$('#prof').fadeIn( "slow").css('background-image','url("images/select2.png")');
```

Can anyone suggest what to do, or what I am doing wrong? I am an absolute beginner in the web development.

After reading the answers, I am adding a few more details to make the problem more clear:

The situation is that there is a sort of sidebar index, containing elements like about, experience, etc. The divs are already visible, what I am doing is when a particular div is selected I want the background image of the div to change. But with the code I am using, the change is happening but too suddenly, I want the transition to be smooth and more aesthetically pleasing, here is the code for an entire section:

```js
$('#about').click(function(){
        $('#contents').css('margin-left','8%');
        $('#contents').css('font-family', "'Quicksand', sans-serif");   
    $('#contents').css('font-size', '1.2em');
    $('#topbar').fadeTo( 2000 , 1);      
        $('#name').text('Dip Ranjan Chatterjee');
        $('#contents').load("about.html #contents > *");
    $('#about').css('background-image','url("images/select2.png")');
    $('#edu').css('background-image','');
    $('#prof').css('background-image','');
    $('#portfolio').css('background-image','');
    $('#sidebar').css('background-image','url("images/sidebar3.png")');
    $('#about').css('color','black');
    $('#about').css('width','55%');
    $('#about').css('margin-top','25%');
    $('#about').css('padding-left','65px');
    $('#about').css('padding-bottom','75px');
    $('#about').css('padding-top','70px');
    $('#about').css('padding-right','15px');


    $('#edu').css('color','white');
    $('#edu').css('width','70%');
    $('#edu').css('padding-left','45px');
    $('#edu').css('padding-bottom','10px');
    $('#edu').css('padding-top','0px');


        $('#prof').css('color','white');
    $('#prof').css('padding-bottom','0px');
    $('#prof').css('padding-top','0px');

    $('#portfolio').css('color','white');
    $('#portfolio').css('padding-bottom','0px');
    $('#portfolio').css('padding-top','0px');


      });
```

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery or CSS3 to run the animation?  Pick one, they are completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly fade-in the background image property of an element. Instead, you can fade in an entire element, so create a div that contains the background image, and fade that in.

CSS

```
   #bg {
      background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
      z-index: -1;
  }
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="bg"></div>
  <div id="prof"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
    $('#prof').click(function(){
        $("#bg").fadeOut(function() {
        $("#bg").css({background : url('images/select2.jpg') });
        $("#bg").fadeIn(300);
       }, 300);
    });
```

The [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this like in css code=you can put this

```
#prof
{
display:none;
}
```

in jquery code you can set like this

```
$('#prof').css('background-image','url("images/select2.png")');
$('#prof').fadeIn("slow");
```

hopefully this may help

Comment: added more details in the question to make it more clear, please look into it once more. thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: when you give all css using jquery after that you can show that div with fadein:slow or when you click on particular div firstly hide this then show it again with fadein effect